# How to detect if a microphone is used by any application

Tags: java, windows, microphone

I wrote a program that changes my light depending on whether I'm in a meeting or not. The easiest way to detect this is to check if the microphone is on. Currently, I check if a microphone icon appears on the screen (OpenCv):
[image]

I'm sure it's not the most optimal solution. Is there any way in Java to detect the fact that a microphone is being used?

Comment: I would say this is not even possible in pure java. I think the only way to find this out is to "ask" the microphone/audio driver. I guess this could maybe be quite easy in linux using alsa and some bash commands but in windows it's probably more difficult... Maybe you have a chance with WMI?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Eskandar Abedini I was able to do it! Below is the entire code:

```
public enum RegistryType {

    MICROPHONE("microphone"),
    WEBCAM("webcam");

    private final String pathValue;

    RegistryType(String pathValue) {
        this.pathValue = pathValue;
    }

    public String getNonPackagePath() {
        return "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\CapabilityAccessManager\\ConsentStore\\" + pathValue + "\\NonPackaged";
    }

}

public class RegistryManager {

    private static final String LAST_USED_TIME_STOP = "LastUsedTimeStop";
    private static final Long LAST_USED_TIME_STOP_VALUE = 0L;

    private RegistryManager() {
    }

    public static boolean isMicrophoneWorking() {
        return isDeviceWorking(MICROPHONE);
    }

    public static boolean isWebcamWorking() {
        return isDeviceWorking(WEBCAM);
    }
    private static boolean isDeviceWorking(final RegistryType registryType) {
        final String[] folders = Advapi32Util.registryGetKeys(WinReg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, registryType.getNonPackagePath());
        return Arrays.stream(folders)
                .map(folder -> registryType.getNonPackagePath() + "\\" + folder)
                .map(register -> Advapi32Util.registryGetLongValue(WinReg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, register, LAST_USED_TIME_STOP))
                .anyMatch(lastUsedTimeStop -> LAST_USED_TIME_STOP_VALUE.compareTo(lastUsedTimeStop) >= 0);
    }

}
```

And I also had to use: https://github.com/java-native-access/jna

Comment: This is the only approach that I found that that actually worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A few years ago I was investigating how to transmit audio through the network, and I wrote simple ugly project.

And to check if a mic is ready to use I used:

```java
javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine microphone = AudioSystem.getTargetDataLine(null);
if (!microphone.isOpen()) {
    // ...
}
```

Maybe it's a bit useless info but I hope it can be useful direction!

Link to class: [MicrophoneReader.java](https://github.com/Shterneregen/java-audio-transceiver/blob/master/src/main/java/random/audio/MicrophoneReader.java)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just because a microphone is ready to use doesn't mean it's being used. Unfortunately, I've tried a similar method and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You may check Windows registry, checking tray or other means for microphone usage

[Detecting if mic/camera is in use?](https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/hcq5qj/detecting_if_miccamera_is_in_use/)

**Note:**

> Microsoft warns that desktop apps can record sound without ever
> notifying Windows. Because they're not subject to the sandbox
> restrictions of Microsoft Store apps, a desktop program can directly
> interface with your microphone hardware. This means malicious software
> could record without Windows being aware, so it won't show up in the
> list or display the microphone icon in the system tray.

[Detecting if mic/camera is in use?](https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/hcq5qj/detecting_if_miccamera_is_in_use/)
[How to see which apps are using your microphone in Windows 10](https://www.onmsft.com/how-to/how-to-see-which-apps-are-using-your-microphone-in-windows-10)

Comment: It is complicated, but I think it is the only method. I need to test it. Thanks!

Comment: Wish successful implementation